# How to uninstall OpenJDK

Tags: java, ubuntu, uninstallation

I just installed Ubuntu, and this is my first time working in a Linux environment.

I'm using wsl2 ubuntu 20.04.5 I accidentally installed too many openjdk. So I want to uninstall them all, but I can't erase them.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQdXi.png)

I tried to uninstall each one, but I failed for the same reason.

Comment: Use apt or dpkg to find installed packages. `ls`  doesn't determined installed packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `openjdk*` in any directory with files of that prefix, it'll expand that glob pattern for them.

I'd suggest not using glob patterns at all.

Java 17 can compile and run Java 8 code, so you should be removing Java 8, explicitly, anyway

Comment: I tried `rm -r -f java-8-openjdk-amd64` But it failed due to Permission denied. Is there a solution?

Comment: Similar answer. `rm` doesn't remove installed Ubuntu packages. Use `apt` or `dpkg`

Comment: When I looked closely at `dpkg`, I could see the exact package name with `dpkg --list`. I solved the problem using `dpkg --purge openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64`. Thank you very, very much.